# Trying to return data asynchronously using jQuery AND jSon in MVC 2.0

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to use Jquerys getJSON method to return data server side to my browser, what happens is the url the getJSON method points to does get reached but upon the postback the result does not get returned to the browser for some odd reason. I wasen't sure if it was because I was using MVC 2.0 and jQuery 1.4.1 and it differs to the MVC 1.0 version and jQuerys 1.3.2 version. . this is the code sections

Controller

```cs
public JsonResult StringReturn() {
    NameDTO myName = new NameDTO();
    myName.nameID = 1;
    myName.name = "James";
    myName.nameDescription = "Jmaes";

    return Json(myName);
}
```

View with JQuery

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("Home/StringReturn/", null, function(data) {
      alert(data.name);
      $("#show").append($("<div>" + data.name + "</div>"));
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```html
<input type="button" value="clickMe" id="myButton"/>
<div id="show">d</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I need to use JsonRequestbehavior inside the return type method to allow get requests

```
return Json(myName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

now it works.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you sure about your path `"Home/StringReturn/"` ?
- Replace `null` with an empty string `""` or just skip it
- Notice this text from [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of JSON data for this reason. JSON is a data-interchange format with syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object literal notation. For example, all strings represented in JSON, whether they are properties or values, must be enclosed in double-quotes. For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/.

Comment: yep, when i debug, it goes to the controller and the result is in the JSon return value, it just doesnt get to the browser somehow, not sure why.

Comment: so $.getJSON() is called ? What does FireBug/Another Debugger say about the XHR request? no response?